# Enterprise Architect Java API

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm trying to find Java API of EA, but I couldn't find any information about it. There are some code with org.sparx.* but I want to see what I can do by using it.
Is there anybody knows how I can get it?

I'm using 10.0.1008 Corporate Edition by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java API allows access to EA:s "Object Model," which is also accessible from C# and from in-EA scripts (which can be written in VBScript, JavaScript or JScript). Through this Object Model you can retrieve and update information in an EA repository.

There is also an "Add-In Model" which, in addition to the Object Model functionality, allows your code to respond to a number of events triggered when the user connects to a repository, creates a diagram, initiates model validation, etc, and also allows you to add your own GUI elements to EA. This Add-In Model is only available through .NET.

Check the help file under Automation and Scripting - Enterprise Architect Object Model. The necessary setup is documented in Using the Automation Interface, and the API in Reference.

Comment: "This Add-In Model is only available through .NET" - not true, it's COM. I was writing VB6 add-ins before .NET was invented ;)

Comment: Absolutely correct, sorry 'bout that. You can in fact write Add-Ins in pretty much the language of your choice. With the possible exception of Prolog.

Comment: The Reference (description of the API) for version 10 is also online here: http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/automation_and_scripting/reference.html

Comment: Can we write EA Add-ins in Java?